# Problem with parbox using pstricks and ticket package

Tags: pstricks, paragraphs

I'm trying to make cards for a game.

I have a problem with `\parbox`. It's working ok only if the `\parbox` in the previous picture is empty. If it's not the contents of `\parbox` are shifted down.

Here is the code and output it makes. Cards go right to left because the ticket package goes top to bottom and I rotated the whole page so the contents of cards are upright.

Why does that happen?

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cutmark]{ticket}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{fp}

\hoffset=-5.0mm
\voffset=-20.0mm

\unitlength=1mm
\ticketNumbers{2}{5}
\ticketSize{85}{55}
\ticketDistance{0}{0}

\newcommand{\pbox}[3]{\parbox{#1}{\center\fontsize{#2}{#2}\selectfont#3}}

\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{}

\newcommand{\myticket}[1]{\ticket{%
\pspicture[unit=10mm](0,0)(5.5,8,5)%
\rput[bl]{90}(8.5,0){%
  \rput[t](2.75,8){\pbox{4cm}{25}{#1}}%
  \psgrid[gridlabels=0,unit=.5,subgriddiv=0,gridwidth=0.1pt](0,0)(11,17)%
}\endpspicture%
}}

\begin{document}
\myticket{}
\myticket{1}
\myticket{2}
\myticket{}
\myticket{3}
\myticket{}
\myticket{}
\myticket{4}
\myticket{5}
\myticket{6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\center` is the start of the `{center}` environment and therefore should be followed by `\endcenter`. You confusing it with `\centering` I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it this way:

```
\newcommand\pbox[3]{\parbox{#1}{\centerline{\fontsize{#2}{#2}\selectfont#3}}}
```

or alternetively:

```
\newcommand\pbox[3]{\makebox[#1]{\fontsize{#2}{#2}\selectfont#3}}
```

Comment: Thanks, both work fine. I forgot to ask why it does happen?

Comment: Your `\center` starts a paragraph with some additional space